# Wrong question and answer counts on "Accounts" tab in SE

Tags: support, user-accounts

https://stackexchange.com/users/124792/enmos-proje?tab=accounts

Similar questions have been asked in the past but they had been solved at the time and had some differences. My problem is that not all but some of my accounts have wrong answer and question counts. You can see it especially in the top three accounts SO, SU, and SF.

Update:

I realized that this has something to do with my merged accounts. Just the sites from my former account have this problem and I guess the numbers do reflect just the Q/A counts of my old account, they aren't being updated with counts from the new account.